# Entity class with Foreign key tables

Tags: asp.net, web-services, entity-framework

In ASP.NET Web API Service model is made of Entity classes that are generated by ADO.NET Entity Framework Data Model database first approach.

When the Model is returned to the client in Service response, data from the Foreign key tables is also returned. For example: Customer table contains Contact table as the Foreign key table.

The Entity Framework generating the POCO (Entity) as below.

```
public partial class Customer
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public FirstName {get;set}
public LastName {get;set;}

//Foreign key table
public virtual Contact Contact {get;set;}
}
```

The Service model is:

```
public class Customer
{
        public Customer customer {get;set;}
}
```

From the API Controller an instance of the model class is created, data is retrieved from the database and returned to the client.

The issue is "when all the records or single record from the Customer table is returned to the client, it is returning the data from Foreign key(Referenced) tables as well. 
Say there are about 100 contacts in Contact table, when a request for one resource is made from the web service client, the data returned is including all the data from the Customer table as well.

Help appreciated to address this behavior.

Regards

Comment: Shouldn't be, as the `virtual` keyword means those related records would be lazy-loaded. Are you using `Include()` win your query?

Comment: How are you confirming that the related data is returned? Are you using a profiler to look at the generated SQL queries? Or are you just checking the collections on the entities? If the latter, then you're probably lazy-loading which will give the false impression that the data exists, when in reality, it's querying on demand.

Comment: @ChrisHardie They would be lazy loaded when it tries to serialize since it's marked as `virtual`. `Include()` is used to eagerly load.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the "LazyloadingEnabled" property to False for the ObjectContext has resolved the issue.

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

More at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456846(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456846%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
        http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/data/jj574232.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when the WebAPI serializes the Customer object, the Contacts collection is being lazily loaded and then serialized.  An option is to manually detach the Customer before returning it.

```
context.Detach(customer);
```

See:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.data.objects.objectcontext.detach(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.data.objects.objectcontext.detach%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738697(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738697%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Eidt:

Consider using Data Transfer Objects (DTO).  This will allow you to control what is being serialized for transfer.  I like to use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) (available via NuGet) to copy data from my EF model to the DTO.

Comment: Generic repository and Unit Of Work patterns are used to interact with the underlying data layer. It is not feasible to detach objects before returning the data. Further help and insight appreciated.

Comment: Hi Chris! POCOs are generated by the ADO.NET Entity Data model wizard, which is adding Virtual key word to the FK objects (Tables). Not using any Include() in the query.

Comment: Hi Justin! JSON Data is returned by the Web API service after serialization. so it is quite transparent.